# Python framework for visualising/animating particles in cartesian space

Tags: python, opengl, animation, 3d, visualization

I have data representing the position of particles for multiple time steps and need to create an animation showing the movement of these particles.

Are there any frameworks or toolkits (ideally Python based) out there does something like this out of the box, or at least something that makes it easy to quickly plot sprites/3d-objects and animate it across multiple time steps?

For the first stage a simple 2D animation is sufficient. However I would like to have the option of extending it further to support 3D and user interaction (changing view, animation control, exporting animation to file, etc).

Just to clarify, I'm not looking to render a complicated scene. Something like the following would do:

[image: sample output]

This particular image is a screenshot of a single frame for a similar data set.

Comment: I know of a book called "Beginning Python Visualization" that might help you. I've no knowledge on Python visualization myself, sorry.

Comment: "...I need something up and running within the next few hours...." - not bloody likely.

Comment: @duffymo I suspected that might be the case. Thought I'd hazard a question just in case there's a wheel out there I could roll on.

Comment: (unrelated) Oddly enough, my link to pyglet disappeared after an edit by @Hansmukh yet the diff does not pick that up. S.O bug? or intentional deletion of an invisible hand?

Comment: Depending on the usage, why you don’t use matplotlib and loop through each time step and save a .jpeg of the charts. Then put the files together as a .gif check: https://pythonprogramming.net/matplotlib-3d-scatterplot-tutorial/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pyprocessing](http://code.google.com/p/pyprocessing/) is a Python treatment of the [processing](http://www.processing.org/) Java animation library.  The processing development environment includes some very nice examples of implementing a particle system.

Comment: I believe you meant this pyprocessing: http://code.google.com/p/pyprocessing/ . I have tinkered with the java version in the past and forgot all about it. Perfect for implementing an initial prototype!

Answer (score 2):

[Houdini by Side Effects Software](http://www.sidefx.com/index.php) is an industry-grade 3D animation application with excellent Python bindings, Python expressions and general support. It would be simple to import your data, and Houdini even has a Python shell within the application for tinkering.

After you've imported it you can take advantage of the full range of animation and visualisation tools and the excellent bundled renderer, "Mantra".

There is a free "[apprentice](http://www.sidefx.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=589&Itemid=221)" edition with very few restrictions, and various levels of paid licenses.

Comment: Thanks. That looks like a very accomplished tool, but perhaps a little to heavyweight for what I need. Will update question with a sample output of what I'm after.

Comment: Incidentally, [Maya](http://autodesk.com/maya) has reasonable Python support too, but to a programmer the whole program is much more restrictive than Houdini.

Answer (score 2):

We've used [pyOGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/PyOgre), which are Python bindings to the OGRE library, which describes itself as:

> What Is OGRE?  OGRE (Object-Oriented
>   Graphics Rendering Engine) is a
>   scene-oriented, flexible 3D engine
>   written in C++ designed to make it
>   easier and more intuitive for
>   developers to produce applications
>   utilising hardware-accelerated 3D
>   graphics. The class library abstracts
>   all the details of using the
>   underlying system libraries like
>   Direct3D and OpenGL and provides an
>   interface based on world objects and
>   other intuitive classes.

Answer (score 2):

In 2D why don't you just use  [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) to do scatter plots of the frames from your simulation.

For example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Just some sample data but I'm assuming that you 
# can get your data into vectors like this.
x = np.random.randn(100)
y = np.random.randn(100)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y, '.')
plt.savefig('frame0000.png')
```

You can then make a video from the frames.

As for 3D - you could try `matplotlib`'s `mlab` or `mplot3D`.  From my experience `mlab` is a bit trickier to get going.  Comment on this post if you need more help with using `matplotlib`.

[http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/mplot3D](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/docs/development/html/mayavi/mlab.html)
http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/docs/development/html/mayavi/mlab.html

Comment: Thanks dtlussier. That would be an improvement on what I have at the moment. However, the reason why I hazarded the question was because I'm eager to add some interactivity to the data --  allowing users to dive into specific regions and pause/replay/slow down etc. This will obviously take a heck of a lot more work than "a few hours", so for the short term, I need to be sure the technology I use can support these requirements.

Comment: What format is your data in at the moment? I do particle viz in Paraview. It definitely provides the type of interaction you're looking for as well as lots of other visualization capabilities.  If you're interested I could send you some information offline to get you started.

Comment: The data is currently in XML should it should be trivial to convert it to any other format. Paraview does seem like something we should consider as a long term solution. We have users running the code in parallel and it would be great to be able to visualise distributed data without having to aggregate it first. My email is shawnchin (AT) gmail. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [PyODE](http://pyode.sourceforge.net/).  That will help with the physics part.  You're on your own with the graphics.

Comment: Thanks. I have stumbled upon that, however I do not need a physics engine. I'm dealing with a simulation program that does all the "clever bits" and spits out the position of each particle after every time step. I'm now trying to display that raw data in a sensible format.